# Apache- Cannot access my page within browse using localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have Apache 2.0.64 running in Windows 7. I visited lots of sites regarding installation and configuration of Apache. My config file is ok (I think). I can stop and restart the server without problems, but when try to access the page (localhost/market) then I get the 'Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost' message.
I have written my RewriteRule within httpd.conf and I donot have .htaccess file in htdocs folder

Some values of my httpd.config may be helpful to you

```
ServerName localhost
Listen 80
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/Apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/Apache/Apache2/htdocs">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(market|stock|mutual)$ stackoverflow/$1 [L]

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Please help me

I don't know what to do anymore...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to access your page with localhost, try to access it with 127.0.0.1 IP address because this IP address points to localhost. Make the .htaccess file writable if it is not. Hope it helps.

Comment: No.. Its not working. Although I have IP 127.0.0.1 as localhost in my hosts file